# Automatically delete overlapping polygons

Tags: qgis, geometry, topology

I have 200 000 polygons that needs to remain like circle and they can't be on top of each other. I need to find a way to correct the 8000 errors I've got automatically.

A picture's worth a thousand words :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Have you implemented topology rules on your data? Are you using ArcGIS?